# grails war file conflit with regular java war file on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

I have two projects: one written in spring framework another in grails.  I tried to deploy them in tomcat (version 6 and 7 ).  Each works well.  However, when I placed them at the same time, Tomcat was stuck.  No errors in log.  It just hangs on there.

When I deleted either of the prjects from webapp of tomcat.  Tomcat began to work again.

Could some one kindly give me some hint or suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: They don't have the same file name do they? E.g. project1.war. Also try increasing the logging level for org.springframework and grails (forgot the package name), so that you see something in the log files that may provide a clue to whats going on (e.g. by comparing the logs with and without the other war file).

Comment: Also check if there are identical package names in both projects with the same class names - maybe copies of those classes being stored in tomcat's work directory are causing a clash (unlikely but worth a try)?

Comment: I had similar situation (Grails + Spring/Spring Roo), both application was working in my case, but very quickly it comes to PermGern OutOfMemory. The only working solution was to run 2 separate TomCats for each application and Lighttpd in front of them as a web proxy. This works and runs stable for weeks.

Comment: Thank you Tom, that is very helpful to know.  Do you know why so?